# How do you skip forward/back while watching a movie in iTunes for Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows

How do you skip forward/back while watching a movie in iTunes for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move forwards or backward within a song/video

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Left</kbd> respectively.

**Reference:** [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/itunes/itns1019/windows)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the hotkeys that I could find:

- Skip back (5 seconds)    : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- Skip forward (5 seconds) : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Chapter previous         : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- Chapter next             : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>